# SetDrawColor() is behaving like SetFillColor()

Tags: php, fpdf

[image]

`SetDrawColor()` supposed to color *Cell frame* but instead another color is rendering as *background color*. This is the whole code :-

```
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->SetTextColor(103, 58, 183);
    $pdf->SetDrawColor(0, 80, 180);
    // Fourth Page --
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, "Hello Santanu", 1, 1, 'C', true);

    $pdf->Output('helo.pdf', 'D');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `SetFillColor` before drawing any cell because it's taking black as default.

```
$pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use SetFillColor() before using SetDrawColor()??